# The canonical projection $\pi:\mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{O}/\mathcal{I}$ factors through the $i_Z^{\flat}:\mathcal{O}_X\to i_{Z*}\mathcal{O}_Z$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a scheme and $\mathcal{I}$ be an ideal of $\mathcal{O}_X$. Then since $\mathcal{O}_X/\mathcal{I}$ is an $\mathcal{O}_X$-module of finite type, $Z=\operatorname{Supp}(\mathcal{O}_X/\mathcal{I})$ is closed.

Assume that

$$ ( Z=\operatorname{Supp}(\mathcal{O}_X/\mathcal{I}),  \mathcal{O}_Z := i_Z^{-1}(\mathcal{O}_X/\mathcal{I}))$$

is a closed subscheme, where $i_Z :Z \hookrightarrow X$ is the inclusion

Let $\pi: \mathcal{O}_X\to \mathcal{O}_X/\mathcal{I}$ be the canonical projection.

Then

Q.1. The canonical morphism $ g:=\varphi^{b} : \mathcal{O}_X/\mathcal{I} \to i_{Z*}(i_Z^{-1}\mathcal{O}_X/\mathcal{I})$ is an isomorphism? Here $g:=\varphi^{b}$ is the morphism induced from the adjunction :

$$ \operatorname{Hom}_{Sh(Z)}(i_Z^{-1}\mathcal{O}_X/\mathcal{I}, i_Z^{-1}\mathcal{O}_X/\mathcal{I}) \to \operatorname{Hom}_{ PreSh(X)}(\mathcal{O}_X/\mathcal{I}, i_{Z*}(i_Z^{-1}\mathcal{O}_X/\mathcal{I}))$$.

Q.2. If so, then $\pi = (\varphi^{b})^{-1} \circ i^{b}_Z$, where $i_Z^{\flat}:\mathcal{O}_X\to i_{Z*}\mathcal{O}_Z$ ?

If this question is not so simple, how about the case that $X=\operatorname{Spec}A$ and $Z=V( \mathfrak{a})$ for some ideal $\mathfrak{a} \subseteq A $?

If these questions are true, then we can show that such $\mathcal{I}$ is quasi-coherent, since

$$\mathcal{I} = \operatorname{ker}(\pi) = \operatorname{ker}( (\varphi^{b})^{-1} \circ i^{b}_Z ) = \operatorname{ker}(i_Z^{\flat}) $$

(final sheaf is quasi coherent).

Anyone helps?